Wheel hub manufacturing difference?
I have a 2013 Honda Civic LX and I need to replace both rear wheel hub assembly. Is there a difference in the US built an Canadian built wheel hubs?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "difference"? A difference in quality? A difference in fitment? Please edit your question and include pertinent bits here.
